# artificial intelligence - implement named entity recognition into AIML

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, chatbot, aiml, alice

Good day, everyone. So I found a paper that implement named entity recognition as pattern in AIML. As far as I know,  in AIML must be uppercase and have no punctuation in it. But in the paper that I mention earlier, they use their pattern with entity and their value e.g Question:DIMANA,Others:LOKASI, etc. So I just want to ask guys, is it possible to write inside  like that? Here is example code that had been provided in the paper.

```
<aiml version="2.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <category>
        <pattern>
            Question:DIMANA,Others:LOKASI,Organization:ITHB
        </pattern>
        <template>
            Lokasi Universitas berada di Jalan....
        </template>
    </category>
</aiml>
```

By the way, I use Python AIML for the intepreter of AIML. Here is the link to the paper: https://journal.ithb.ac.id/telematika/article/view/130 (the paper is in Bahasa)

Comment: What happened when you tried it?  Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.

Comment: Well it was not detected. But the reason I am asking this question is if it possible in some way that I didn't know.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to tell without reading the full paper. But:

```
Question:DIMANA,Others:LOKASI,Organization:ITHB
```

is not a valid AIML pattern as it should not contain commas or colons, and it should be upper case. My guess is the authors of the paper use some pre-processor to insert valid AIML pattern strings in place of the **Question**, **Others** and **Organization** elements.

Comment: I provided the link to the paper if you want to read it. But I think your explanation is make sense. Thank you.